# Android studio App module under main project is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing new problem in android studio. My app under project name is not displaying in bold letter like volley and pull to refresh are looking. So that i am not able to run my project. Please help me if you know the solution.

Comment: what version is your android studio?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin  latest vesion 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your ***settings.gradle*** file. This file specifies which of the projects are included in the build. It should have something like this for app module to be included in project:

```
include ':app'...
```

If not, then include this and perform a gradle sync.

Comment: Thanks @KKD, I am also facing this issue and now it is solved so thank u very much...